# How to skip 'Reinitialized existing Git repository' on Gitlab CICD Stage

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

Below is my YML file structure. I want the following up stages to be run without reinitializing the git repository. The git repository should only be initialized during the first stage, which is the build stage.

```
variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: fetch

stages:
  - build
  - run_test
  - run_test2

build_job:
    variables:
        test_env: "test"
    stage: build
    script:
        - "powershell -File ./Scripts/BuildSolution.ps1"
    only:
        refs:
          - TDD-G2

run_test:
    variables:
        test_env: "test"
    stage: run_test
    script:
        - "powershell -File ./Project1/scripts/RunSelenium.ps1"
    artifacts:
        when: always
        paths:
          - ./Project1/TestResults

run_test2:
    variables:
        test_env: "test"
    stage: run_test2
    script:
        - "powershell -File ./Project2/scripts/RunSelenium.ps1"
    artifacts:
        when: always
        paths:
          - ./Project2/TestResults
```

Comment: could you please give a hint, have you solved the question? I've faced with the same situation.

Answer (score 11):

I was facing quite similar problem and where I had three stage's build, test and deploy. In deploy stage i wanted to create a tag something [like](https://neron-joseph.medium.com/tag-your-git-repo-using-gitlabs-ci-cd-pipeline-a7963c2274d2) But I was facing a strange issue where even after deleting the tag from remote (Note: i was working alone on this project) the pipeline was failing continuously saying the tag already exists. But after some time the same job completed successfully.

To fix this I set the strategy to `clone`(Explained below) only for deploy(Git repository was reinitializing again here) job but for build and test it is fetch(default option). As

```
variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone
```

For GitLab:

> Git strategy
>
> Introduced in GitLab Runner 8.9.
>
> By default, GitLab is configured to use the fetch Git strategy, which
> is recommended for large repositories. This strategy reduces the
> amount of data to transfer and does not really impact the operations
> that you might do on a repository from CI.

There are two options. Using:

- git clone: which is slower because it clones the repository from scratch for every job
- git fetch: which is **default** in GitLab and faster as it re-uses the local working copy (falling back to clone if it doesn’t exist). This is recommended, especially for large repositories.

Detail Read is [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#git-strategy) and [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html#git-strategy)

Hope it help to someone who came to this issue.

Answer (score 9):

You could use the variable `GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS` to instruct the gitlab-runner to call `git clean` in a constrained way. For example, by specifying `none`, you could disable calling `git clean` alltogether, so files produced by the previous stage won't be deleted.

```
run_test:
    variables:
        test_env: "test"
        GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: none
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#git-clean-flags
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/large_repositories/#git-clean-flags

Answer (score 3):

This is what you are looking for:

```
job1:
  variables:
    GIT_CHECKOUT: "false"
```

Use that variable in the job where you want to skip checking out the repo. Make sure the GIT_STRATEGY you are using on your project on GitLab is either 'clone' or 'fetch', otherwise it won't work.

Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#git-checkout

Comment: Exactly what I have been looking for!